# iphone - dynamically change nib for tab

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, nib

I'm developing a tabbar app that for a certain edge case needs to load a nib that's not the nib I connected to that tab in the Interface Builder.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use IB simply to indicate you'll have a UITabBarController. You need not define the tabs there. Then in your code you can programatically create UIViewControllers for each tab you want to expose. Perhaps at this point is where you can decide to show your special edge case tab or not.

Comment: You're right, I can programatically create UIViewControllers for each tab but from what I found that all happens when the application is launched.  I don't know how to change this after the app is launched.

Comment: UITabBarController gives you access to its viewControllers array. Look into how you can update that array's individual elements. You may only be able to change the entire array wholesale, if at all. Not entirely sure. You might have to create your own UITabBarController class -- not necessarily a sub-class especially if UITabBarController won't let you change tabs post-launch at all.

Answer (score 0):

Everything done in Interface Builder has a programmatic way of doing it so I am sure that this is possible. Check out the [viewControllers property of the UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/viewControllers).